# SpringData-Neo4j - New value must be a Set, was: class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to persist a domain object that contains fields of type java.util.List. I am using springdata 3.2.0.RELEASE + Neo4j 2.1.2 and persisting the object using neo4jTemplate.save API.

The questions is:
How to handle a scenario where domoain object has a list.

appreciate your assistance

Utpal.

I am getting the following error:

```
INFO : org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DelegatingFieldAccessorFactory - No FieldAccessor configured for field: interface java.util.Set ratings rel: false idx: false
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: New value must be a Set, was: class java.util.ArrayList
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelationshipHelper.createSetOfTargetNodes(RelationshipHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToFieldAccessor.createSetOfTargetNodes(RelatedToFieldAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessor.setValue(RelatedToCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.setValue(DefaultEntityState.java:113)
```

Comment: Can you show your entity (or entities) and persisting code?

Answer (score 1):

Use Set rather than List. Neo4j doesn't support order.

It will help.